# DateRangePicker not working for "Today" but working with other options

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-daterangepicker

**Using DateRangePicker** [github](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

When choosing Dates i store it in `HTML` in separate `div` elements as `Start Date` and `End Date`. The plugin is working fine. One thing i don't undestand is

> Choose `Today` from Dropmenu. Only for the first time its not passing
>   any data to `<div>`. If i choose any other option for the first its
>   working fine.

Find JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tpsdwp8j/1/)

**What i'm trying to do is?**
*On Date selection write `startdate` and `enddate` to `<div>`.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Just Adding `startdate` and `enddate` its working. Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpsdwp8j/2/)

Comment: click on the apply button first time.